# Node.js Api throwing CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: node.js, sql-server, vue.js, cors

i am getting below error while consuming node.js function from my vue.js application.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://0.0.0.0:1081/sendsecondarysalesreport' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:1050' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Here is my Node.js code.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const router = express.Router()

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
});
var corsOptions = {
    "origin": "http://0.0.0.0:1050",
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "preflightContinue": false,
    "optionsSuccessStatus": 200
}
router.use(cors(corsOptions));
router.options('/*', (_, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

router.options('/sendsecondarysalesreport', cors(corsOptions));
router.post('/sendsecondarysalesreport', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (req.body.CustomerCode != "") {
            SendSecondarySalesReport(req.body)
            res.json([{ "CustomerCode": req.body.CustomerCode }]);
        } else {
            res.send({ "Status": false, "Error": "Not Found" })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        res.status(500)
        res.send(error.message)
    }
});
module.exports = router ;
```

Here is my client side code

```
this.$http.post(helper.URL() + 'sendsecondarysalesreport', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then((response) => {
          if (response.status == "200") {
}
```

Please help me solve the issue.

I have tried many solutions available here and every time the result is same. Its working fine in my development server but after hosting in iis this issue is coming.

Comment: Aside... the default is `optionsSuccessStatus: 204`, did you mean to use 200 here?

Comment: There's a lot of `cors()` stuff going on there. As a starting point have you tried: commenting out all references of `cors(corsOptions)`; commenting out both `router.use(...)` invocations and replacing them with a single `router.use(cors())`? That should get CORS basically working, then you can start locking it down further.